# How can I sum up the values of two functions? (2.0)

Tags: python, inheritance, tkinter

As I promised yesterday, here comes the real code.

I am about to code a program, for defining the reverberation time in a room. Explaining the whole project, takes too much time. I tried the approach which was suggested, but I do something wrong...

In **PageOne**, there are all the degrees of absorption of the materials in different sound frequencies and in **PageTwo**, the user has to enter the area in square meters and choose the material. As soon as the OK-button is pressed the functions getBottomChoice and getWallChoice multiply the values of the materials in PageOne with the userinput, to get the absorption area. But unfortunately it doesn't work. And how can I  print out the new values(absorption area) of the chosen materials, just for checkin out? And last but not least, how can I sum up the  abs.areas of the chosen materials and print it out, listed by the frequencies ? Thanks in advance!

````
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *
import math
LARGE_FONT = ("Verdana", 12)



class ReverberationTime(tk.Tk):


    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):


        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "reverberation time")
        tk.Tk.iconbitmap(self,"C:/Users/PC/Desktop/Icons/speaker.ico")

        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)    
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo, PageThree):

            frame = F(container, self)

            self.frames[F] = frame

            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self,cont):

        frame = self.frames[cont]

        frame.tkraise()



class Pages:
    p = 0
    z = 1
    abs_flä = 1

    def __init__(self):

        self.parkett_125 = 0.04
        self.parkett_250 = 0.04
        self.parkett_500 = 0.05
        self.parkett_1000 = 0.06
        self.parkett_2000 = 0.06
        self.parkett_4000 = 0.06

        self.linoleum_125 = 0.02
        self.linoleum_250 = 0.02
        self.linoleum_500 = 0.03
        self.linoleum_1000 = 0.03
        self.linoleum_2000 = 0.04
        self.linoleum_4000 = 0.04

        self.pvc_125 = 0.02
        self.pvc_250 = 0.02
        self.pvc_500 = 0.01
        self.pvc_1000 = 0.03
        self.pvc_2000 = 0.05
        self.pvc_4000 = 0.05

        self.tapete_125 = 0.02
        self.tapete_250 = 0.03
        self.tapete_500 = 0.04
        self.tapete_1000 = 0.05
        self.tapete_2000 = 0.07
        self.tapete_4000 = 0.08

        self.glattputz_125 = 0.02
        self.glattputz_250 = 0.02
        self.glattputz_500 = 0.03
        self.glattputz_1000 = 0.03
        self.glattputz_2000 = 0.04
        self.glattputz_4000 = 0.06

        self.mauerziegelwand_125 = 0.02
        self.mauerziegelwand_250 = 0.02
        self.mauerziegelwand_500 = 0.03
        self.mauerziegelwand_1000 = 0.04
        self.mauerziegelwand_2000 = 0.05
        self.mauerziegelwand_4000 = 0.06

    def bottoms(self,parkett_125,parkett_250,parkett_500,parkett_1000,
                parkett_2000,parkett_4000,linoleum_125,linoleum_250,linoleum_500,
                linoleum_1000,linoleum_2000,linoleum_4000,pvc_125,
                pvc_250,pvc_500,pvc_1000,pvc_2000,pvc_4000):

        self.parkett_125 = parkett_125
        self.parkett_250 = parkett_250
        self.parkett_500 = parkett_500
        self.parkett_1000 = parkett_1000
        self.parkett_2000 = parkett_2000
        self.parkett_4000 = parkett_4000

        self.linoleum_125 = linoleum_125
        self.linoleum_250 = linoleum_250
        self.linoleum_500 = linoleum_500
        self.linoleum_1000 = linoleum_1000
        self.linoleum_2000 = linoleum_2000
        self.linoleum_4000 = linoleum_4000

        self.pvc_125 = pvc_125
        self.pvc_250 = pvc_250
        self.pvc_500 = pvc_500
        self.pvc_1000 = pvc_1000
        self.pvc_2000 = pvc_2000
        self.pvc_4000 = pvc_4000  

    def walls(self,tapete_125,tapete_250,tapete_500,tapete_1000,tapete_2000,tapete_4000,
              glattputz_125,glattputz_250,glattputz_500,glattputz_1000,glattputz_2000,glattputz_4000,
              mauerziegelwand_125,mauerziegelwand_250,mauerziegelwand_500,mauerziegelwand_1000,mauerziegelwand_2000,mauerziegelwand_4000):

        self.tapete_125 = tapete_125
        self.tapete_250 = tapete_250
        self.tapete_500 = tapete_500
        self.tapete_1000 = tapete_1000
        self.tapete_2000 = tapete_2000
        self.tapete_4000 = tapete_4000

        self.glattputz_125 = glattputz_125
        self.glattputz_250 = glattputz_250
        self.glattputz_500 = glattputz_500
        self.glattputz_1000 = glattputz_1000
        self.glattputz_2000 = glattputz_2000
        self.glattputz_4000 = glattputz_4000

        self.mauerziegelwand_125 = mauerziegelwand_125
        self.mauerziegelwand_250 = mauerziegelwand_250
        self.mauerziegelwand_500 = mauerziegelwand_500
        self.mauerziegelwand_1000 = mauerziegelwand_1000
        self.mauerziegelwand_2000 = mauerziegelwand_2000
        self.mauerziegelwand_4000 = mauerziegelwand_4000


class StartPage(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="reverberation time", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady = 10, padx = 10)

        button = ttk.Button(self, text="welcome!", 
                            command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne)).pack()


class PageOne(tk.Frame, Pages):


    def __init__(self, parent, controller):


        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        NORMAL_FONT=("Arial",11)

        title = tk.Label(self, text="Please enter the room dimensions.", font=LARGE_FONT)
        title.pack(pady = 10, padx = 10)

        frame = Frame(self)
        frame.pack(pady=20)

        self.lenght = StringVar()
        self.width = StringVar()
        self.height = StringVar()
        self.v = StringVar()

        dimensions = Frame(frame)
        dimensions.pack(side='left', pady=5)

        entryfields = Frame(frame)
        entryfields.pack(side='right', pady=5)

        lblLenght = Label(dimensions, text="lenght:", font=NORMAL_FONT)
        lblLenght.pack(pady=3)
        lblWidth = Label(dimensions, text="width:", font=NORMAL_FONT)
        lblWidth.pack(pady=4)
        lblHeight = Label(dimensions, text="height:", font=NORMAL_FONT)
        lblHeight.pack(pady=4)
        lblVolume = Label(dimensions, textvariable = self.v)
        lblVolume.pack()


        entLength = Entry(entryfields, textvariable = self.lenght)
        entLength.pack(pady=6)
        entWidth = Entry(entryfields, textvariable = self.width)
        entWidth.pack(pady=6)
        entHeight = Entry(entryfields, textvariable = self.height)
        entHeight.pack(pady=6)


        btncalculate = ttk.Button(self, text="calculate")
        btncalculate.pack()
        btncalculate.bind("<Button-1>", self.calculate)

        btnPageTwo = ttk.Button(self, text="Page 2", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        btnPageTwo.pack()

        btnStartPage = ttk.Button(self, text="Start Page", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        btnStartPage.pack()



    def calculate(self, carryout):
        try:
            l = float(self.lenght.get())
            b = float(self.width.get())
            h = float(self.height.get())
            m = l*b*h
            self.v.set("volume: % .2f m³" % m)
            Pages.p = m

        except ValueError:
            tk.messagebox.showinfo('No valid input.','Please enter only numbers!',icon = 'warning')


class PageTwo(tk.Frame, Pages):

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        NORMAL_FONT=("Arial",11)

        title = tk.Label(self, text="Please select the bottom abilities.", font=LARGE_FONT)
        title.pack(pady = 10, padx = 10)

        self.bottomMaterial =StringVar()
        self.bottom = StringVar()

        self.wallMaterial =StringVar()
        self.wall = StringVar()

        frame = Frame(self)
        frame.pack(pady=20)

        dimensions = Frame(frame)
        dimensions.pack(side='left', pady=5)

        entBottom = Entry(dimensions, textvariable = self.bottom)
        entBottom.grid(pady = 5)
        self.cboBottomMaterial = ttk.Combobox(dimensions, textvariable = self.bottomMaterial, state = 'readonly',font = ('arial', 14, 'bold'), width = 19)
        self.cboBottomMaterial ['value'] = ('Parkett', 'Linoleum', 'PVC')
        self.cboBottomMaterial.current(0)
        self.cboBottomMaterial.grid()
        btnBottomChoice = ttk.Button(dimensions, text = "OK", command = self.getBottomChoice)
        btnBottomChoice.grid()

        entWall = Entry(dimensions, textvariable = self.wall)
        entWall.grid(pady = 5)
        self.cboWallMaterial = ttk.Combobox(dimensions, textvariable = self.wallMaterial, state = 'readonly',font = ('arial', 14, 'bold'), width = 19)
        self.cboWallMaterial ['value'] = ('Tapete', 'Glattputz', 'Mauerziegelwand')
        self.cboWallMaterial.current(0)
        self.cboWallMaterial.grid()
        btnWallChoice = ttk.Button(dimensions, text = "OK", command = self.getWallChoice)
        btnWallChoice.grid()

        btnsumAbsorptionArea = ttk.Button(self, text="sum")
        btnsumAbsorptionArea.pack()
        btnsumAbsorptionArea.bind("<Button-1>", self.sumAbsorptionArea)



        btnPageTwo = ttk.Button(self, text="Page 1", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        btnPageTwo.pack()

        btnStartPage = ttk.Button(self, text="Start Page", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        btnStartPage.pack()

        btnStartPage = ttk.Button(self, text="Page 3", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageThree))
        btnStartPage.pack()

    def getBottomChoice(self):

            if self.cboBottomMaterial.get() == "Parkett":
                self.bottoms(
               self.parkett_125 * float(self.bottom.get()),
               self.parkett_250 * float(self.bottom.get()),
               self.parkett_500 * float(self.bottom.get()),
               self.parkett_1000 * float(self.bottom.get()),
               self.parkett_2000 * float(self.bottom.get()),
               self.parkett_4000 * float(self.bottom.get())
               )

            elif self.cboBottomMaterial.get() == "Linoleum":
                self.bottoms(
               self.linoleum_125 * float(self.bottom.get()),
               self.linoleum_250 * float(self.bottom.get()),
               self.linoleum_500 * float(self.bottom.get()),
               self.linoleum_1000 * float(self.bottom.get()),
               self.linoleum_2000 * float(self.bottom.get()),
               self.linoleum_4000 * float(self.bottom.get())
               )

            elif self.cboBottomMaterial.get() == "PVC":
               self.bottoms(
               self.pvc_250 * float(self.bottom.get()),
               self.pvc_500 * float(self.bottom.get()),
               self.pvc_1000 * float(self.bottom.get()),
               self.pvc_2000 * float(self.bottom.get()),
               self.pvc_4000 * float(self.bottom.get())
               )

            elif self.cboBottomMaterial.get() == "":
                messagebox.showinfo('No valid input.','Please select.',icon = 'warning')



    def getWallChoice(self):

            if self.cboWallMaterial.get() == "Tapete":
                self.walls(
               self.tapete_125 * float(self.wall.get()),
               self.tapete_250 * float(self.wall.get()),
               self.tapete_500 * float(self.wall.get()),
               self.tapete_1000 * float(self.wall.get()),
               self.tapete_2000 * float(self.wall.get()),
               self.tapete_4000 * float(self.wall.get())
               )

            elif self.cboWallMaterial.get() == "Glattputz":
                self.walls(
               self.glattputz_125 * float(self.wall.get()),
               self.glattputz_250 * float(self.wall.get()),
               self.glattputz_500 * float(self.wall.get()),
               self.glattputz_1000 * float(self.wall.get()),
               self.glattputz_2000 * float(self.wall.get()),
               self.glattputz_4000 * float(self.wall.get())
               )

            elif self.cboWallMaterial.get() == "Mauerziegelwand":
               self.walls(
               self.mauerziegelwand_250 * float(self.wall.get()),
               self.mauerziegelwand_500 * float(self.wall.get()),
               self.mauerziegelwand_1000 * float(self.wall.get()),
               self.mauerziegelwand_2000 * float(self.wall.get()),
               self.mauerziegelwand_4000 * float(self.wall.get())
               )

            elif self.cboWallMaterial.get() == "":
                messagebox.showinfo('No valid input.','Please select.',icon = 'warning')


    def sumAbsorptionArea(self,sum):

        sum = self.getBottomChoice + self.getWallChoice
        print (sum)


class PageThree(tk.Frame, Pages):


    def passvariable(self, var):
            self.s.set("volume: % .2f m³" % Pages.p)

    def absorptionsrate(self, var):
            self.abs_rate.set("volume: % .2f m³" % Pages.abs_flä)

    def __init__(self, parent, controller):

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        frame = Frame(self)
        frame.pack(pady=20)

        result_var = StringVar()
        selected_var = StringVar()
        self.s = StringVar()
        items_for_listbox = ["Musik","Sprache","Vortrag","Spr.+Vor.","Sport"]
        self.abs_rate = StringVar()

        def select(event):

            a = mylistbox.get(ANCHOR)
            Pages.z = curselection(a) 
            selected_var.set(Pages.z)

        def curselection(a):

            if a=="Musik":
                T_soll_A1 = 0.45*math.log10(Pages.p)+0.07                
                return (T_soll_A1)

            elif a=="Sprache":
                T_soll_A2 = 0.37*math.log10(Pages.p)-0.14             
                return (T_soll_A2)

            elif a=="Vortrag":
                T_soll_A3 = 0.32*math.log10(Pages.p)-0.17               
                return (T_soll_A3)

            elif a=="Spr.+Vor.":    
                T_soll_A4 = 0.26*math.log10(Pages.p)-0.14           
                return (T_soll_A4)

            elif a=="Sport":    
                T_soll_A5 = 0.75*math.log10(Pages.p)-1              
                return (T_soll_A5)

        def calc():

                if mylistbox.get(ACTIVE):
                    Abs_Fl_ges = 0.163 * Pages.p / Pages.z
                    Absorber = Abs_Fl_ges - Pages.abs_flä
                    result_var.set(Absorber) 

                elif Pages.z == 0:
                    messagebox.showinfo("No selection")

        self.dimension = Frame(frame)
        self.dimension.pack(side='left', pady=5)

        lblPageTwo = tk.Label(self, text="Page 2", font=LARGE_FONT)
        lblPageTwo.pack(pady = 10, padx = 10)

        lblAbs_rate = tk.Label(self.dimension, textvariable = self.abs_rate)
        lblAbs_rate.pack()

        pasvar = tk.Label(self.dimension, textvariable = self.s)
        pasvar.pack()

        lblselection = tk.Label(self.dimension, textvariable=selected_var)
        lblselection.pack(expand=YES)
        selected_var.set("No selection")


        lblresult = Label(self.dimension, textvariable=result_var)
        lblresult.pack(expand=YES)
        result_var.set("No result")

        listbox_frame = Frame(self.dimension)
        listbox_frame.pack(expand=YES)

        mylistbox = Listbox(listbox_frame, height=5, width=10, font=('times',18))
        mylistbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', select)
        mylistbox.grid(row=0, column=0)
        mylistbox.insert(END, *items_for_listbox)

        scroll = Scrollbar(listbox_frame, orient=VERTICAL) # the alignment of the scrollbar
        mylistbox["yscrollcommand"] = scroll.set # link the list with the scroll
        scroll["command"] = mylistbox.yview # link the scroll with the scroll
        scroll.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N+S) #sticky=N+S+E)

        btnAbsorber=Button(self.dimension, text="Fläche der Absorber", command=calc)
        btnAbsorber.pack(expand=YES)

        btnStartPage = ttk.Button(self, text="Start Page", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage))
        btnStartPage.pack()

        btnPageOne = ttk.Button(self, text="Page 1", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne))
        btnPageOne.pack()

        btnPageTwo = ttk.Button(self, text="Page 2", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo))
        btnPageTwo.pack()

        btnPassVariable = ttk.Button(self, text="pasvariable")
        btnPassVariable.pack()
        btnPassVariable.bind("<Button-1>", self.passvariable)

        btnAbs_rate = ttk.Button(self, text="pass absorption rate")
        btnAbs_rate.pack()
        btnAbs_rate.bind("<Button-1>", self.absorptionsrate)



app = ReverberationTime()
app.mainloop() ```
````

Comment: I see 2 issue at a glance. You are not importing tkinter as tk and your indention is incorrect. It should be 4 spaces

Comment: so many errors in the code! Even the imports are messed - `from tkinter import *` and then in `class ReverberationTime(tk.TK)`

Comment: You've posted way too much code. Please create a [mcve].  Stackoverflow isn't a free debugging service for complete programs. You need to focus on a single, small problem, and include just enough code to illustrate the problem.

Comment: ahh, ok, thanks for the advice!!

Comment: @Mike-SMT: neither of those things you mentioned are errors, they are personal preferences. While it would be good if they adhered to best practices, that's not really related to the question being asked.

Comment: @BryanOakley The import is in error. They use `tk.Tk` but do not import as `tk`. Also they are using `messagebox` but do not import it either.

Comment: @BryanOakley: I tried by the post yesterday, but I am unable to assume the tipps to my code, sorry..

Comment: ok, I changed `from tkinter import *` to `import tkinter as tk` and added `from tkinter import messagebox`, but is still doesn't work...

Comment: I am aware it still wont work. If you pay attention to the errors you get while doing things You will get other errors related to class attributes. Your `Pages` class may not be inherited properly in your PageOne class for example. When I tried something I got `AttributeError: 'PageTwo' object has no attribute 'linoleum_125'`. So there is a problem there.

Comment: Maybe instead of trying to inherit from `Frame` and `Pages` you just inherit `Frame` and then define an instance of `Pages` as an attribute.

Comment: @Mike-SMT: ok thanks, I'll try it out and let you know if I had success!!

Comment: @Mike-SMT: hmm... These two functions are defined in the class `Pages`. So I call the functions in class `PageTwo` with the help of `getBottomChoice` and `getWallChoice`...is that what you mean?

Comment: Ya but I just realized that and fixed it on my end. That leads us t another problem. Your 2 functions only send a few arguments to a method that requires many more. `bottoms` and `walls` take a lot of arguments so your 2 functions will cause errors. To correct this you may want to simply update the variables directly or have default variables in your methods.

Comment: Also your methods `getBottomChoice` and `getWallChoice` do not return anything so your line `the_sum = self.get_bottom_choice + self.get_wall_choice` cant do any math. So what exactly did you expect `self.get_bottom_choice + self.get_wall_choice` to do. Sum everything or just sum the values looked from whatever `elif` condition was met?

Comment: ok I see your point. I am afraid this is the only solution. too bad, thanks anyway!!

Comment: That what is the only solution? I need to know what you are expecting from that line of code so I can fix the functions.

Comment: I expected to sum the "new" values, created by user`s choice and yes, from whatever elif condition was met. I think I recognized that is too complicated for me...I have to find another simple solution...puuhhh

Answer (score 1):

Ok so going off of our conversation in the comments and some assumptions I had to make about how things connect I have refactored your code.

Let me know if anything is not working as exspected.

1. 4 spaces for indention is the standard. It helps with readability and if you follow the standard you can avoid issues like mismatching indention.
2. Make sure you have all your imports in your examples as this is an important troubleshooting step and lets us know what libraries we may need to test your examples.
3. I have refactored your code to follow the PEP8 standard. You had a mix of formatting going on and nothing was consistent.
4. It can be tricky to inherit from multiple classes so instead inherit from `Frame` and then create a class attribute that is an instance of `Pages`
5. Your functions that create new values from the attributes in Pages doesn't work like you are expecting. Instead you will want to sum everything then return that summed value.
6. Your math in your `sumAbsorptionArea` method cannot work as you are using a reference to methods instead of executing those methods.
7. You use a mix of `command` and `bind` on your buttons for some reason and because of this you have to have an event variable in some of your functions/methods. Instead just use command.
8. Personally you use a lot of lines up for defining attributes. I would work out a way to shorten this. Preferable a list of values or a dictionary would work well here. You can work that one out on your own though. :D

Refactored code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import messagebox
import math
LARGE_FONT = ("Verdana", 12)


class ReverberationTime(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        tk.Tk.wm_title(self, "reverberation time")
        # tk.Tk.iconbitmap(self, "C:/Users/PC/Desktop/Icons/speaker.ico")
        container = tk.Frame(self)
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)
        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}
        for F in (StartPage, PageOne, PageTwo, PageThree):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.show_frame(StartPage)

    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()


class Pages:
    p, z, abs_flä = 0, 1, 1

    def __init__(self):
        self.parkett_125 = 0.04
        self.parkett_250 = 0.04
        self.parkett_500 = 0.05
        self.parkett_1000 = 0.06
        self.parkett_2000 = 0.06
        self.parkett_4000 = 0.06
        self.linoleum_125 = 0.02
        self.linoleum_250 = 0.02
        self.linoleum_500 = 0.03
        self.linoleum_1000 = 0.03
        self.linoleum_2000 = 0.04
        self.linoleum_4000 = 0.04
        self.pvc_125 = 0.02
        self.pvc_250 = 0.02
        self.pvc_500 = 0.01
        self.pvc_1000 = 0.03
        self.pvc_2000 = 0.05
        self.pvc_4000 = 0.05
        self.tapete_125 = 0.02
        self.tapete_250 = 0.03
        self.tapete_500 = 0.04
        self.tapete_1000 = 0.05
        self.tapete_2000 = 0.07
        self.tapete_4000 = 0.08
        self.glattputz_125 = 0.02
        self.glattputz_250 = 0.02
        self.glattputz_500 = 0.03
        self.glattputz_1000 = 0.03
        self.glattputz_2000 = 0.04
        self.glattputz_4000 = 0.06
        self.mauerziegelwand_125 = 0.02
        self.mauerziegelwand_250 = 0.02
        self.mauerziegelwand_500 = 0.03
        self.mauerziegelwand_1000 = 0.04
        self.mauerziegelwand_2000 = 0.05
        self.mauerziegelwand_4000 = 0.06


class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        label = tk.Label(self, text="reverberation time", font=LARGE_FONT)
        label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)
        button = ttk.Button(self, text="welcome!",
                           command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne)).pack()


class PageOne(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        super(PageOne).__init__()
        self.Pages = Pages()
        normal_font = ("Arial", 11)
        tk.Label(self, text="Please enter the room dimensions.", font=LARGE_FONT).pack(pady=10, padx=10)
        frame = tk.Frame(self)
        frame.pack(pady=20)
        self.length = tk.StringVar()
        self.width = tk.StringVar()
        self.height = tk.StringVar()
        self.v = tk.StringVar()
        dimensions = tk.Frame(frame)
        dimensions.pack(side='left', pady=5)
        entry_fields = tk.Frame(frame)
        entry_fields.pack(side='right', pady=5)

        tk.Label(dimensions, text="length:", font=normal_font).pack(pady=3)
        tk.Label(dimensions, text="width:", font=normal_font).pack(pady=4)
        tk.Label(dimensions, text="height:", font=normal_font).pack(pady=4)
        tk.Label(dimensions, textvariable=self.v).pack()
        tk.Entry(entry_fields, textvariable=self.length).pack(pady=6)
        tk.Entry(entry_fields, textvariable=self.width).pack(pady=6)
        tk.Entry(entry_fields, textvariable=self.height).pack(pady=6)

        ttk.Button(self, text="calculate", command=self.calculate).pack()
        ttk.Button(self, text="Page 2", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo)).pack()
        ttk.Button(self, text="Start Page", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage)).pack()

    def calculate(self):
        try:
            l = float(self.length.get())
            b = float(self.width.get())
            h = float(self.height.get())
            m = l*b*h
            self.v.set("volume: % .2f m³" % m)
            self.Pages.p = m
        except ValueError:
            tk.messagebox.showinfo('No valid input.', 'Please enter only numbers!', icon = 'warning')


class PageTwo(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        # normal_font = ("Arial", 11)  # not used
        self.Pages = Pages()
        title = tk.Label(self, text="Please select the bottom abilities.", font=LARGE_FONT)
        title.pack(pady=10, padx=10)
        self.bottomMaterial = tk.StringVar()
        self.bottom = tk.StringVar()
        self.wallMaterial = tk.StringVar()
        self.wall = tk.StringVar()
        frame = tk.Frame(self)
        frame.pack(pady=20)
        dimensions = tk.Frame(frame)
        dimensions.pack(side='left', pady=5)
        tk.Entry(dimensions, textvariable=self.bottom).grid(pady=5)
        self.cboBottomMaterial = ttk.Combobox(dimensions, textvariable=self.bottomMaterial,
                                              state='readonly', font=('arial', 14, 'bold'), width=19)
        self.cboBottomMaterial['value'] = ('Parkett', 'Linoleum', 'PVC')
        self.cboBottomMaterial.current(0)
        self.cboBottomMaterial.grid()
        ttk.Button(dimensions, text="OK", command=self.get_bottom_choice).grid()
        tk.Entry(dimensions, textvariable=self.wall).grid(pady=5)
        self.cboWallMaterial = ttk.Combobox(dimensions, textvariable=self.wallMaterial,
                                            state='readonly', font=('arial', 14, 'bold'), width=19)
        self.cboWallMaterial['value'] = ('Tapete', 'Glattputz', 'Mauerziegelwand')
        self.cboWallMaterial.current(0)
        self.cboWallMaterial.grid()

        ttk.Button(dimensions, text="OK", command=self.get_wall_choice).grid()
        ttk.Button(self, text="sum", command=self.sum_absorption_area).pack()
        ttk.Button(self, text="Page 1", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne)).pack()
        ttk.Button(self, text="Start Page", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage)).pack()
        ttk.Button(self, text="Page 3", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageThree)).pack()

    def get_bottom_choice(self):
        if self.cboBottomMaterial.get() == "Parkett":
            parkett_125 = self.Pages.parkett_125 * float(self.bottom.get())
            parkett_250 = self.Pages.parkett_250 * float(self.bottom.get())
            parkett_500 = self.Pages.parkett_500 * float(self.bottom.get())
            parkett_1000 = self.Pages.parkett_1000 * float(self.bottom.get())
            parkett_2000 = self.Pages.parkett_2000 * float(self.bottom.get())
            parkett_4000 = self.Pages.parkett_4000 * float(self.bottom.get())
            return sum([parkett_125, parkett_250, parkett_500, parkett_1000, parkett_2000, parkett_4000])
        elif self.cboBottomMaterial.get() == "Linoleum":
            linoleum_125 = self.Pages.linoleum_125 * float(self.bottom.get()),
            linoleum_250 = self.Pages.linoleum_250 * float(self.bottom.get())
            linoleum_500 = self.Pages.linoleum_500 * float(self.bottom.get())
            linoleum_1000 = self.Pages.linoleum_1000 * float(self.bottom.get())
            linoleum_2000 = self.Pages.linoleum_2000 * float(self.bottom.get())
            linoleum_4000 = self.Pages.linoleum_4000 * float(self.bottom.get())
            return sum([linoleum_125, linoleum_250, linoleum_500, linoleum_1000, linoleum_2000, linoleum_4000])
        elif self.cboBottomMaterial.get() == "PVC":
            pvc_250 = self.Pages.pvc_250 * float(self.bottom.get()),
            pvc_500 = self.Pages.pvc_500 * float(self.bottom.get())
            pvc_1000 = self.Pages.pvc_1000 * float(self.bottom.get())
            pvc_2000 = self.Pages.pvc_2000 * float(self.bottom.get())
            pvc_4000 = self.Pages.pvc_4000 * float(self.bottom.get())
            return sum([pvc_250, pvc_500, pvc_1000, pvc_2000, pvc_4000])
        elif self.cboBottomMaterial.get() == "":
            messagebox.showinfo('No valid input.', 'Please select.', icon='warning')
            return 0

    def get_wall_choice(self):
        if self.cboWallMaterial.get() == "Tapete":
            tapete_125 = self.Pages.tapete_125 * float(self.wall.get())
            tapete_250 = self.Pages.tapete_250 * float(self.wall.get())
            tapete_500 = self.Pages.tapete_500 * float(self.wall.get())
            tapete_1000 = self.Pages.tapete_1000 * float(self.wall.get())
            tapete_2000 = self.Pages.tapete_2000 * float(self.wall.get())
            tapete_4000 = self.Pages.tapete_4000 * float(self.wall.get())
            return sum([tapete_125, tapete_250, tapete_500, tapete_1000, tapete_2000, tapete_4000])
        elif self.cboWallMaterial.get() == "Glattputz":
            glattputz_125 = self.Pages.glattputz_125 * float(self.wall.get())
            glattputz_250 = self.Pages.glattputz_250 * float(self.wall.get())
            glattputz_500 = self.Pages.glattputz_500 * float(self.wall.get())
            glattputz_1000 = self.Pages.glattputz_1000 * float(self.wall.get())
            glattputz_2000 = self.Pages.glattputz_2000 * float(self.wall.get())
            glattputz_4000 = self.Pages.glattputz_4000 * float(self.wall.get())
            return sum([glattputz_125, glattputz_250, glattputz_500, glattputz_1000, glattputz_2000, glattputz_4000])
        elif self.cboWallMaterial.get() == "Mauerziegelwand":
            mauerziegelwand_250 = self.Pages.mauerziegelwand_250 * float(self.wall.get())
            mauerziegelwand_500 = self.Pages.mauerziegelwand_500 * float(self.wall.get())
            mauerziegelwand_1000 = self.Pages.mauerziegelwand_1000 * float(self.wall.get())
            mauerziegelwand_2000 = self.Pages.mauerziegelwand_2000 * float(self.wall.get())
            mauerziegelwand_4000 = self.Pages.mauerziegelwand_4000 * float(self.wall.get())
            return sum([mauerziegelwand_250, mauerziegelwand_500, mauerziegelwand_1000,
                        mauerziegelwand_2000, mauerziegelwand_4000])
        elif self.cboWallMaterial.get() == "":
            messagebox.showinfo('No valid input.', 'Please select.', icon='warning')
            return 0

    def sum_absorption_area(self):
        the_sum = self.get_bottom_choice() + self.get_wall_choice()
        print(the_sum)


class PageThree(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, controller):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.Pages = Pages()
        self.s = tk.StringVar()
        self.result_var = tk.StringVar()
        self.selected_var = tk.StringVar()
        self.selected_var.set("No selection")
        self.result_var.set("No result")
        self.abs_rate = tk.StringVar()
        items_for_listbox = ["Musik", "Sprache", "Vortrag", "Spr.+Vor.", "Sport"]

        frame = tk.Frame(self)
        frame.pack(pady=20)
        self.dimension = tk.Frame(frame)
        self.dimension.pack(side='left', pady=5)
        tk.Label(self, text="Page 2", font=LARGE_FONT).pack(pady=10, padx=10)
        tk.Label(self.dimension, textvariable=self.abs_rate).pack()
        tk.Label(self.dimension, textvariable=self.s).pack()
        tk.Label(self.dimension, textvariable=self.selected_var).pack(expand='yes')
        tk.Label(self.dimension, textvariable=self.result_var).pack(expand='yes')

        listbox_frame = tk.Frame(self.dimension)
        listbox_frame.pack(expand='yes')
        self.mylistbox = tk.Listbox(listbox_frame, height=5, width=10, font=('times', 18))
        self.mylistbox.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self.select)
        self.mylistbox.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.mylistbox.insert('end', *items_for_listbox)

        scroll = tk.Scrollbar(listbox_frame, orient='vertical')  # the alignment of the scrollbar
        self.mylistbox["yscrollcommand"] = scroll.set  # link the list with the scroll
        scroll["command"] = self.mylistbox.yview  # link the scroll with the scroll
        scroll.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky='ns')  # sticky=N+S+E)

        tk.Button(self.dimension, text="Fläche der Absorber", command=self.calc).pack(expand='yes')
        ttk.Button(self, text="Start Page", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(StartPage)).pack()
        ttk.Button(self, text="Page 1", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageOne)).pack()
        ttk.Button(self, text="Page 2", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(PageTwo)).pack()
        ttk.Button(self, text="pasvariable", command=self.pass_variable).pack()
        ttk.Button(self, text="pass absorption rate", command=self.absorptions_rate).pack()

    def curselection(self, a):
        if a == "Musik":
            return 0.45 * math.log10(self.Pages.p) + 0.07
        elif a == "Sprache":
            return 0.37 * math.log10(self.Pages.p) - 0.14
        elif a == "Vortrag":
            return 0.32 * math.log10(self.Pages.p) - 0.17
        elif a == "Spr.+Vor.":
            return 0.26 * math.log10(Pages.p) - 0.14
        elif a == "Sport":
            return 0.75 * math.log10(Pages.p) - 1

    def calc(self):
        if self.mylistbox.get('active'):
            abs_fl_ges = 0.163 * Pages.p / Pages.z
            absorber = abs_fl_ges - Pages.abs_flä
            self.result_var.set(absorber)

        elif Pages.z == 0:
            messagebox.showinfo("No selection")

    def select(self, _=None):
        a = self.mylistbox.get('anchor')
        self.Pages.z = self.curselection(a)
        self.selected_var.set(self.Pages.z)

    def pass_variable(self):
        self.s.set("volume: % .2f m³" % self.Pages.p)

    def absorptions_rate(self):
        self.abs_rate.set("volume: % .2f m³" % self.Pages.abs_flä)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ReverberationTime().mainloop()
```

Comment: Hey Mike. First of all, I am pleasantly surprised how fast and passionately you want to help me. Thanks for all. Ok, I  see you use another strategy. You define all the variables in class Pages without any methods and so you can change their the values directly in class PageTwo. But unfortunately it doesnt work. As soon as I click the upper OK-button for bottom-choice I get an error. The lower OK-button is not connected, there is no reaction if I click it. And finally, the `sum_absorption_area`-function doesn't do anything :) :)

Comment: here is the error: ` File "E:/Python/Akustik/Akustik/Test2.py", line 185, in get_bottom_choice
    return sum([pvc_250, pvc_500, pvc_1000, pvc_2000, pvc_4000])
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple' `

Comment: @Jionny odd. That error does not occur on my end. I wonder where the tuple is comming from. I have a meeting to go to but I will take another look when I get back. Tell me what imputes you are using and what you are expecting to get out and I will take a look when I get back. Just so you know when I press sum I get a value printed to screen without errors. So maybe its something specific you are using I need to try.

Comment: Now I tried it in Spyder and Jupyter Notebook, both depicte this error :) maybe I do something wrong... ok see you later!!

Comment: @Jionny What imputes are you using?

Comment: sorry, english is not my native language...do you mean what kind of digits I enter in the entries? If I enter float numbers, the sum button works...but only if I choose "parkett" for example. if I choose "linoleum" the error appears.

Comment: Ok I can also enter integers, but it works only by selecting "parkett"

Comment: Ok, now I corrected the little miststake, you had a komma in linoleum and pvc in the first line :)

Comment: Ah ya. They were leftovers I missed when I converted it.

Comment: Ok thanks for your support...but actually I don´t need the OK-buttons right?

Comment: @Jionny from what I see it doesnt look like the OK buttons are needed. You can just do everything from the SUM button.

Comment: Ok thanks for all....Now I think I have to stop this project and learn the basics at first, because this project is too big for my knowledge :)